# Освобождение ресурсов, выделенных потоку

Tags: c, память, unix, freebsd, pthread

Всем добрый день!
Хотелось бы обсудить следующую проблему : в программе средствами библиотеки pthread создается поток, ОС выделяет ему некоторый обьем памяти на стек и т.п., после того, как данный поток отработал и завершился, из другого потока вызывается *pthread_join()*, забирающая код возврата. При этом, не заметно, чтобы память, выделенная для данного потока, освобождалась (при вызове *pthread_create()* выделилось порядка 100 кб, из которых ничего не освободилось ни после *return()*, ни после *pthread_join()*). Кто-нибудь может пояснить, почему? Я что-то не так делаю, или это может быть обусловлено поведением ОС ?

Comment: Необязательно память выделенная и освободившаяся реально возвращается в систему. Это оптимизационное свойство. При вторичном запросе памяти она может быть выделена из пула, что происходит намного быстрее. Кстати, та же история и с malloc/free.

Comment: дело в том, что если я после уничтожения первого потока, создаю второй, количество выделенной памяти снова растет на 100 Кб, при создании следующего - еще плюс 100 и т.д.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что об этом не следует очень сильно беспокоиться.

Comment: а нет ли у Вас подходящей ссылки на то, что так подсказывает ?

Comment: [Это][1]

[1]:http://www.magister.msk.ru/library/philos/lossky/lossky01.htm

Comment: занимательно кончено, но не подойдет :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[[[@margosh](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh), я тоже (солидарно с [[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg) и почти интуитивно) считаю, что память, которую брал поток, используется повторно. Иллюстрацию приведу прямо здесь.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define fatal(msg) ({perror(msg); exit(-1);})

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int nth = 0;

void *
thcli (void *a)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  nth--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

  return (void *)1;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int i, n = av[1]? atoi(av[1]):100;
  if (n < 1)
    n = 100;
  pthread_t th[n];
  void *res[n];
  char buf[100];

  do {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (pthread_create (&th[i], NULL, thcli, NULL))
        fatal("create");
      nth++;
    }
    printf ("run %d nth = %d\n",i,nth);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (pthread_join (th[i], &res[i]))
        fatal("join");
    }
    printf ("join %d nth = %d\nAgain ?\n",i,nth);
  } while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin), buf[0] == 'y');

  exit (puts("Bye") == EOF);
}
```

Обилия инклюдов не пугайтесь, большая часть  на нужны, просто скопировал для этого тестика из другой программы.

А вот и иллюстация

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$ gcc th.c -pthread
.....
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$ ./a.out 381
create: Cannot allocate memory
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$ ./a.out 380
run 380 nth = 380
join 380 nth = 0
Again ?
y
run 380 nth = 380
join 380 nth = 0
Again ?
y
run 380 nth = 380
join 380 nth = 0
Again ?
y
run 380 nth = 380
join 380 nth = 0
Again ?
.
Bye
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$ ./a.out 380
run 380 nth = 380
join 380 nth = 0
Again ?
y
run 380 nth = 380
join 380 nth = 0
Again ?
.
Bye
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$ ./a.out 381
create: Cannot allocate memory
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$
```

IMHO видно, что если ресурса почти достаточно, то после завершения потоков он опять высвобождается и повторно используется (по крайней мере в такой же ситуации).

**UPD-1**

[[[[@margosh](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh), у меня в линуксе не растет. Добавил функцию

```
// returns second field for last line selected by  'what'
static int
pri_mem (int pid, char **what)
{
  char path[1000];
  int  res = 0;

  sprintf (path,"/proc/%d/status",pid);
  FILE *in = fopen(path,"r");
  if (!in) {
    perror(path);
    return;
  }
  while (fgets(path,1000,in)) {
    char **w = what;
    while (*w) {
      if (strncasecmp(path,*w,strlen(*w)) == 0) {
        fputs(path,stdout);
        char dummy[1000];
        sscanf(path,"%s %d",dummy,&res);
        break;
      }
      w++;
    }
  }
  fclose(in);

  return res;
}
```

и чуть изменил main(), теперь печатает память перед каждым циклом

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$ gcc th.c -pthread
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$ ./a.out 380
VmPeak:     2252 kB
VmSize:     2252 kB
VmHWM:       312 kB
VmRSS:       312 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 380 nth = 380
loop 0: join 380 nth = 0
Exit ?

VmPeak:  3116732 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:      2180 kB
VmRSS:       680 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 380 nth = 380
loop 1: join 380 nth = 0
Exit ?

VmPeak:  3116736 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:      2192 kB
VmRSS:       692 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 380 nth = 380
loop 2: join 380 nth = 0
Exit ?

VmPeak:  3116736 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:      2192 kB
VmRSS:       692 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 380 nth = 380
loop 3: join 380 nth = 0
Exit ?
```

и дальше

```
VmPeak:  3116736 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:      2192 kB
VmRSS:       692 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 380 nth = 380
loop 29: join 380 nth = 0
Exit ?
VmPeak:  3116736 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:      2192 kB
VmRSS:       692 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 380 nth = 380
loop 30: join 380 nth = 0
Exit ?
VmPeak:  3116736 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:      2192 kB
VmRSS:       692 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 380 nth = 380
loop 31: join 380 nth = 0
Exit ?
y
Bye
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$
```

IMHO не растет. Попробуем с небольшим количеством потоков

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$ ./a.out 30
VmPeak:     2252 kB
VmSize:     2252 kB
VmHWM:       316 kB
VmRSS:       316 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 30 nth = 30
loop 0: join 30 nth = 0
Exit ?

VmPeak:   248132 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:       728 kB
VmRSS:       628 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 30 nth = 30
loop 1: join 30 nth = 0
Exit ?

VmPeak:   248136 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:       740 kB
VmRSS:       640 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 30 nth = 30
loop 2: join 30 nth = 0
Exit ?

.......
.......

loop 15: join 30 nth = 0
Exit ?

VmPeak:   248136 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:       740 kB
VmRSS:       640 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 30 nth = 30
loop 16: join 30 nth = 0
Exit ?

VmPeak:   248136 kB
VmSize:    35044 kB
VmHWM:       740 kB
VmRSS:       640 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
run 30 nth = 30
loop 17: join 30 nth = 0
Exit ?
y
Bye
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$
```

Возможно проблема в FreeBsd.

Comment: Да, вполне видно. У Вас Ubuntu? Вы не могли бы повторить эксперимент и запустить с ним одновременно TOP. Будет ли увеличиваться память в графе RES при прохождении нескольких итераций?

Comment: @margosh, посмотрел (но мышью захватить и копипастнуть не смог).

RES меняется  (636, 636, ... 1160, 836, 636, 636, 1160) совсем по кругу или нет, не знаю.

Comment: вот. а у меня почему-то меняется, и это меня очень смущает. Попробую Ваш примерчик запустить, спасибо Вам!

Comment: @margosh, так ведь и у меня меняется, только похоже циклически. А у Вас постоянно растет? 

Может где-то free() не вызываете, или FILE \* (или что-то подобное) не закрываете?

Comment: @avp, протестировала ваш примерчик у себя, в нем память растет постоянно, но на небольшую величину - 2-4 Кб. Попробовала передавать в поток структуру, паямть под нее выделяю динамически до *pthread_create()*, освобождаю после join, - растет, но не на постоянную величину, например при запуске 500 потоков первый раз память 4292, второй - 4504, третий - 4588, и т.д. тоесть прирост используемой памяти уменьшается, но все равно остается.

Comment: @avp,По поводу того, что не освобождаю память где-то думала разумеется, но при пошаговой отладке программы вижу, что львиная доля памяти выделяется сразу после *pthread_create()* (около 100 Кб) еще в начале функции на этапе обьявления переменных, а после завершения потока освобождается порядка 4 кб (немного больше передаваемой в поток структуры данных)

Comment: @margosh, в **UPD-1** печатаю размеры памяти.

Comment: @avp, можно целый проект, чтобы сохранить в файл и скомпилировать. Не вижу, где вызывается pri_mem().

@margosh, выложи вывод программы @avp, собранной под FreeBsd. Вот этой новой версии, которая выводит информацию о памяти. Сравним.

Comment: @mikeslv, только сейчас заметил Ваш комментарий.


      char *what[] = {"vmpeak","vmsize","vmhwm","vmrss","vmstk",NULL};
    
      do {
        pri_mem (getpid(),what);
    .....

Вот тут вызывается. Не знаю, в FreeBsd будет ли работать (там /proc-то есть?).

Собирается тривиально

    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/tst$ gcc th.c -pthread

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что никто не сказал про `pthread_detach()`. Помнится если его не запускать память выделенная под поток не освобождается и очень шустро растет, что очень заметно например в htop. Я вызываю эту штуку после pthread_create().

```
pthread_t restrict;
if(pthread_create(&restrict, ...)) return 0;
pthread_detach(restrict);
return 0;
```

"Функция pthread_join блокирует работу вызвавшей ее нити исполнения до завершения thread'а с идентификатором thread." Не вижу никакой связи с использованием памяти. Она тут не при чем.

Comment: @mikelsv, после pthread_detach() вызов pthread_join() для этого потока не работает (а автор в вопросе как раз говорит об использовании pthread_join()).

Использование attached и detached потоков подразумевают несколько разные алгоритмы обработки.

Comment: Жаль, что не видите, приведу цитату из Стивенса "Вызов функции *pthread_join()* автоматически переводит поток в обособленное состояние, которое позволяет вернуть ресурсы потока обратно". Мне в данном случае детач не подходит, так как я хочу после завершения потока узнать код завершения.

Comment: @avp, возможно, в FreeBSD управление выделением памяти реализовано отлично от Linux, я пока, к сожалению не нашла на эту тему ничего стоящего. Немного успокаивает то, что прирост памяти постепенно снижается, но хотелось бы выяснить, почему вообще прирост в потреблении есть.

Comment: Ага, тоже вариант. Потестировал пример @avp, ничего не утекает. Может не в потоках дело? Проверь на утечки памяти в valgrind или ищи ошибки.

Comment: @margosh, скорее всего [вот это](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-threads/2005-December/003319.html) уже давно исправлено, но что-то аналогичноое (обратите внимание на \_pthread_mutex_destroy) возможно у Вас есть.

Comment: @mikelsv, Вы под FreeBSD тестировали? какая версия? Как я уже упоминала в предыдущих комментах, дело в потоках, и в чем-то, чего я возможно о них не знаю. Valgrind у меня утечек не находит, но по прежнему падает на некой инструкции, на какой именно - не говорит, можете глянуть мои предыдущие темы, если интересно.
@avp, может быть, буду копать дальше...

Comment: Тестировал в 6 Центосе. Если решусь, поставлю FreeBSD дабы посмотреть, как пойдет там. Почитал темы, довольно интересные вопросы. Valgrind падает даже в дебаге? Я в таком случае отлаживал с помощью printf(), раскидав их по всей программе. Было бы здорово увидеть код программы, без него обсуждения получаются слегка философскими. :)

Comment: Я бы и не стал его сильно анализировать. Меня интересует общий вид, основная логика, какие функции используются и что еще есть интересного. А дальше б я напичкал проект printf(), собрал и погонял под valgrind.

Comment: @margosh, [здесь](http://nick-black.com/dankwiki/index.php/Pthreads) говорят, что транслировать с FreeBSD's libc надо с -D_THREAD_SAFE.

Может быть дело в этом?

Comment: @mikelsv, уже было, пока без результатов. Общий вид будет, когда руки дойдут. По этому поводу могу добавить пока только, что это многопоточный сервер, в 2 потока рабоатют постоянно - 1 обслуживает приходящие соединения, 1 подчищает за всеми память,плюс создаются отдельные потоки для каждого подсоединенного клиента, в каждом из которых создается дочерний процесс, с коим клиент общается. уже интересно, не правда ли? :)

Comment: @margosh, судя по описанию 1 делает join для получения кода возврата? А ведь 1 как-то должен узнать, что уже можно-нужно вызвать join.

Можно переделать это с возвратом кода (и может еще адресов, что подчистить надо) через pipe (общий для 1 (только он читает) и всех клиентов (они только пишут)), а поток для клиента делать detached. 


pipe опрашивается в том же select(или poll), что и входящие соединения. Писать в него надо одним вызовом write.


IMHO проще будет.

Comment: @margosh, да интересно... было бы на это посмотреть. Так же было бы интересно посмотреть на тему оптимизации. Например для чего нужен процесс подчищающий память, эту задачу можно было бы решать в других процессах. И зачем дочерний процесс в каждом потоке? Если только запускать какую-то программу. Хмм, будет лишнее время, напишу программку по типу вашей, как ее вижу.

Answer (score 0):

лимит комментов исчерпан.
[@avp](/users/232/avp), -D_THREAD_SAFE не спас. Возможно, прийдется пересмотреть логику очищения, в любом случае попробую  и с detach для разнообразия, вдруг изменится чего. да, join сейчас только 1 поток делает, когда получает признак через pipe(), как Вы мне когда-то подсказали уже, за что большое спасибо :)

Comment: @mikelsv, не процесс, а поток! подчищающий память - чтобы остальным не мешать, т.е. чтобы главный поток, принимающий соединения, не тратил на это время и чтобы клиенты не простаивали в ожидании. Процесс в каждом потоке - именно, запускает копию программы, и поток с ней общается.

Comment: @avp, кстати, если Вам интересно, под FreeBSD не провести такой же вот, как у Вас в примере, замер расходуемой памяти, т.к. файл /proc/PID/status содержит другую информацию, типа :  
cat /proc/31668/status
fl_sd 31668 1 31668 31668 - sldr 1352376252,694798 1,131754 3,548299 select 0 0 0,0,5 -  
пояснений к параметрам я сходу не нашла, а при запуске нескольких итераций программы меняются они явно иначе, чем в приведенном листинге, так что интуитивно неясно какой из них за что отвечает.

Comment: @margosh, в linux описание файлов из /proc в `man 5 proc`. 

В BSD - не знаю, но попробуйте (если он есть) посмотреть cat /proc/[PID]/statm

    1362 71 57 11 0 74 0

    size       total program size
               (same as VmSize in /proc/[pid]/status)
    resident   resident set size
               (same as VmRSS in /proc/[pid]/status)
    share      shared pages (from shared mappings)
    text       text (code)
    lib        library (unused in Linux 2.6)
    data       data + stack
    dt         dirty pages (unused in Linux 2.6)

IMHO числа в страницах по 4К.

Comment: не, такого нету, есть только /proc/PID/status, и он выглядит ровно так, как я привела выше, и описаний по proc в мане нету.

Comment: Ну, на нет и суда нет.

[Поситрите](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/07/c_c_tip_how_get_process_resident_set_size_physical_memory_use) может найдете что-то подходящее. Может getrusage()  подойдет, но в linux он мало информации о памяти возвращает.